# AppStore の「ベスト新着App」と「ベスト新着ゲーム」に表示されているアプリのリストを取得したい

Tags: app-store

Appleにフィーチャーされるアプリの傾向を調べるために、AppStoreおすすめタブの「ベスト新着App」と「ベスト新着ゲーム」を取得してログに保存したいと思っております。
iTunesAPIを使えばアプリの名前やレーティングが取得できるようでしたが、ベスト新着Appに取り上げられているアプリを取得する、といったことはできないようでした。
情報を直接取得することができないのであれば、AppStoreのアプリをウェブスクレイピングして情報を吸い出すということはできませんでしょうか？
お詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Comment: どの言語で処理をしたいのでしょうか?

Comment: 個人的にphpであればありがたいですが、
AppStoreのおすすめアプリを取得する手法を知りたいと思っているので、基本的にはどの言語でもＯＫです。

Comment: [RSS Generator](http://rss.itunes.apple.com/ja-jp)でiTunesのランキング情報のRSSが取得できるのですが、質問の「ベスト新着○○」と、パラメータにある「おすすめ新着○○」が同じものなのか別物なのかわかりません。

Answer (score -1):

[http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/sf=143441/limit=100/genre=6007/xml[1](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/sf=143441/limit=100/genre=6007/xml)
これでできると思います
(追記)ここのリンクからxml解析を行えば取得することができると思います

Comment: 他のサイトに答えが書かれている場合でも、要点を回答内に記載し、リンクはあくまで参考情報にとどめてください。リンク先が変更・削除された場合に回答の価値が失われることも防ぎます。 - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15198)

Comment: 他サイトに答えが書いてあるわけではなく、データの取得先URLを提示しました。

Comment: しかもこれ itunes.apple.com 下なんですね（こういうときは，リンクにしてしまうより URL を見せたほうがいいと思います）． `genre` とかについてどっかにドキュメントとかあってもよさそうですが，もしあれば追記されるとより有用かと思います．

Comment: "Top Free Applications in Productivity"とあるように、これは「ベスト新着App」が取得できるRSSではないと思いますが

Comment: そうですね。でもtopとあるんで…